# Show that $\cot^{-1}[\frac{xy+1}{x-y}]+\cot^{-1}[\frac{yz+1}{y-z}]+\cot^{-1}[\frac{zx+1}{z-x}]=n\pi$ where $n$ is an integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

**Show that $\displaystyle \cot^{-1}\left[\frac{xy+1}{x-y}\right]+\cot^{-1}\left[\frac{yz+1}{y-z}\right]+\cot^{-1}\left[\frac{zx+1}{z-x}\right]=n\pi$ where $n$ is an integer.**

I substituted $x=\tan\alpha$, $y=\tan\beta$, $z=\tan\gamma$ and simplified it as

$\cot^{-1}\left[\cot(\alpha-\beta)\right]+\cot^{-1}\left[\cot(\beta-\gamma)\right]+\cot^{-1}\left[\cot(\gamma-\alpha)\right]$

and then

$(\alpha-\beta)+(\beta-\gamma)+(\gamma-\alpha)=0$.

What did I do wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\cot^{-1}(\cot x) \ne x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$: You were close, except the correct formula is

$$\cot^{-1}(\cot(x)) = x - \pi \left\lfloor\frac{x}{\pi}\right\rfloor$$

for $x\neq n\pi$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I totally forgot that last part. Thank you so much!